# How to edit XML node using combobox (VB.Net)

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to edit the Income node, and am achieving this with the current code. However all other elements (RptMenu and Icon) are being removed. I want them to remain in the XML file and only Income to be changed to whatever the textbox sets. A combobox is used to select which MenuItem (Income, Stock etc) is to be changed.

XML Code: (There are more menu items not included to keep it simple)

```
<ReportMenu>

<RptMenu category="Menu">
    <MenuItem>Income</MenuItem>
    <Icon>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Menu\Menu\Resources\IncomeImage.jpg</Icon>
  </RptMenu>

<RptMenu category="Menu">
    <MenuItem>Stock</MenuItem>
    <Icon>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Menu\Menu\Resources\IncomeImage.jpg</Icon>
  </RptMenu>

 </ReportMenu>
```

vb.net Code:

```
Private Sub btnEditCategory_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEditCategory.Click

Dim xd As New XmlDocument()
        xd.Load("C:\Documents\Reports.xml")

        Dim newNode As XmlElement = xd.CreateElement("MenuItem")
        newNode.InnerText = txtAddCategory.Text

        For Each oldNode As XmlNode In xd.SelectNodes("ReportMenu/RptMenu")

            If oldNode.SelectSingleNode("MenuItem").InnerText = cmbCategory.Text Then
                oldNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, oldNode)
            End If

        Next
        xd.Save("C:\Documents\Reports.xml")

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Profiles>
<Name>
</Name>
</Profiles>
```

**OR**

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Profiles.xml")
ComboBox1.DataSource = (From element In doc.Descendants("Name") Select element.Value).ToList()
```

**Demo:**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1faf99bd-f22e-4f52-aa0a-2d4328835537/c-change-xml-node